# Using purrr::invoke() to supply different arguments to function.

Tags: r, purrr

I want to run the `kmeans()` function in R with different values of k (`kmeans(x = iris[1:4], centers = k)`). I know how to do this with dplyr or the `do.call()` function, however I can't get it to work with `purrr::invoke()` (I'm quite sure that invoke is the right function for this task). I could of course just use the dplyr approach (see [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/kmeans.html)), but it annoys me that I can't get it to work with purrr.

In the `purrr::invoke()` function reference, the following code-example is included:

```
# Or the same function with different inputs:
invoke_map("runif", list(list(n = 5), list(n = 10)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0.67176682 0.05861411 0.99706914 0.14903547 0.51855664
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 0.84612005 0.71826972 0.24131402 0.54704337 0.83480182 0.02795603
#>  [7] 0.46938430 0.80568003 0.81405131 0.40391100
#>
```

When i try to do this with `kmeans` i get the following

```
> invoke(kmeans, list(list(centers = 1), list(centers = 2)), x = iris[1:4])
Error in sample.int(m, k) : invalid 'size' argument
```

I have also tried

```
> invoke(kmeans, list(centers = 1:5), x = iris[1:4])
Error in (function (x, centers, iter.max = 10L, nstart = 1L, 
algorithm = c("Hartigan-Wong",  : must have same number of columns in 'x' and 'centers'
```

as a reality-check, i also tried doing a similar thing with `paste`

```
> invoke(paste, list(list(sep = "a"), list(sep = "b")), "word1", "word2")
[1] "a b word1 word2"
```

where i would've expected `word1aword2` and `word1bword2`. I have been reading all the function references and I'm currently not sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you "quite sure that invoke is the right function for this task"?

A simple `map` does:

```
set.seed(123) ; res1 <- invoke_map(kmeans, transpose(list(centers = 1:10)), x = iris[1:4])

set.seed(123) ; res2 <- map(1:10, kmeans, x = iris[1:4])

identical(res1, res2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: The function reference confused me. It stated that "This pair of functions make it easier to combine a function and list of parameters to get a result.". i thought i had to use invoke to supply named commands, and I am a bit surprised that the map approach works, since centers argument isn't named.

Comment: One could indeed argue that there's a bit of "uncleanness" in this solution, since it relies on positioning arguments: it works because `centers` is the second argument of `kmeans`, after `x`, and since `x` is specified in `...`, it is equivalent to `map`ping `partial(kmeans, x = iris[1:4])`, of which the first argument is `centers`. Apologies if I'm adding to the confusion.

Comment: No it actually makes a lot of sense, thanks for explaining how it works! I came to realize that i could supply the name with an anonymous function. `map(1:10, ~kmeans(centers = .x, x = iris[1:4]))`. This would perhaps make it more readable.

Comment: Sure, I was about to also suggest that. It's also a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what went wrong. First of all, the correct function to use in this case is `invoke_map()` and not `invoke()`. When using this function (as also specified in the function reference -.-), the problem can be solved with the following code:

```
invoke_map(kmeans, list(list(centers = 1), list(centers = 2)), x = iris[1:4])
```

This can however be quite tedious to write if you want multiple centers, so i came up with the following solution which im quite happy with. Hope this can help someone else!

```
invoke_map(kmeans, transpose(list(centers = 1:10)), x = iris[1:4])
```